# How can I scroll or control chromium browser or Chrome webpage using selenium and python3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium, rangeslider

I have a specific python3 code/script that I have written to automate with selenium for writing of some form in a webpage. the issue arises when the form input box is present down the webpage. So much down that I have to scroll down before the script gets executed. If I don't scroll down the following error gets displayed

```
 '''selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (144, 1018)
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)'''
```

A little description of the webpage, there are 16 form boxes in 4x4 pattern, i.e. web page has 4 rows and 4 columns. At the extreme bottom there is button of 'save' that needs to be clicked after the forms are filled properly. The problem now is that while the selenium 'send.keys' does its job perfectly the 'driver.find_element_by_xpath('the_x_path').click()' doesn't do its job. Rather the 'driver.click()'. Command does scroll to the option but doesn't actually click. I have tried typing the same code (driver.find_element_by_xpath('the_x_path').click()) twice but doesn't yield any results except the above code. Now as I have said previously if I manually scroll down the webpage while the script is catching up the script works perfectly so if there is any way to scroll down or up the webpage, I need help with that. Another way is as I've discussed with all of you above in the 5th line of this paragraph. the first click() command does navigate to the actual button/link but doesn't does the actualy 'click'. Instead throws up the above error, so my proposition is that if I type the same command then it might help. Well I still don't have much faith in the 2nd proposal. need some help thus. Really appreciate for reading this out. Thanks.